# Writing text under the theorem, example, definition

Tags: newtheorem

So, using `\theoremstyle` to create example, definition, and theorem, by default the text would be inline with the their title like this;

```
Example 1.1 bla bla
Bla bla bla
```

But can i move the text under the title, so the output would be:

```
Example 1.1
bla bla 
Bla bla bla
```

How to do this? I don't have a MWE for this, cz i confuse how to start with. I hope you understand my question and want to help me.

Comment: Please add an example of small document with your theorems. We need to know, which document class and theorem environments you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `ntheorem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\begin{document}
\begin{example}
    Let us consider the example of \dots
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and with `amsthm` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{break}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}%
  {}{}%
  {\bfseries}{}%
  {\newline}{}%

\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\begin{document}
\begin{example}
    Let us consider the example of \dots
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]